# Why does creating a list change the result of shapiro.test?

Tags: r, list

Why do the results of `x` anc `y` differ?

```
[1] 0 0 0 1
[1] 0.06 0.06 0.22 0.19
```

Here is the code (from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/2498/209028)):

```
rands <- list()
set.seed(1)
rands[[1]] <- rnorm(10) + c(1,0,2,0,1)
rands[[2]] <- rnorm(100) + c(1,0,2,0,1)
rands[[3]] <- rnorm(1000) + c(1,0,2,0,1)
rands[[4]] <- rnorm(5000) + c(1,0,2,0,1)

x <- replicate(100, { # generates 100 different tests on each distribution
  c(shapiro.test(rands[[1]])$p.value,
    shapiro.test(rands[[2]])$p.value,
    shapiro.test(rands[[3]])$p.value,
    shapiro.test(rands[[4]])$p.value)}) # rnorm gives a random draw from the normal distribution

set.seed(1)
y <- replicate(100, { # generates 100 different tests on each distribution
  c(shapiro.test(rnorm(10) + c(1,0,2,0,1))$p.value,
    shapiro.test(rnorm(100) + c(1,0,2,0,1))$p.value,
    shapiro.test(rnorm(1000) + c(1,0,2,0,1))$p.value,
    shapiro.test(rnorm(1000) + c(1,0,2,0,1))$p.value)}) # rnorm gives a random draw from the normal distribution

print(rowMeans(x < 0.05)) # the proportion of significant deviations
print(rowMeans(y < 0.05)) # the proportion of significant deviations
```

I also checked:

```
class(rands[[1]]) # [1] "numeric"
class(rnorm(10) + c(1,0,2,0,1)) # [1] "numeric"
```

and e.g.

```
rands[[1]]
# [1] 0.3735462 0.1836433 1.1643714 1.5952808 1.3295078 0.1795316 0.4874291 2.7383247 0.5757814 0.6946116
set.seed(1)
rnorm(10) + c(1,0,2,0,1)
# [1] 0.3735462 0.1836433 1.1643714 1.5952808 1.3295078 0.1795316 0.4874291 2.7383247 0.5757814 0.6946116
```

I fear, I make a studid mistake?

Comment: `x` keeps all random numbers identical, whereas in `y`, you are drawing "fresh" random numbers in each of the 100 replications. If you look at e.g. `x`, you will see that these are actually 100 identical tests. So, you probably want to go with `y` if you intend to draw new random numbers each time.

Comment: @coffeinjunky You mean, the `replicate` is the crucial part destroying my intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify the problem, consider the following:

```
set.seed(1)
rands[[1]] <- rnorm(10) + c(1,0,2,0,1)
x <- replicate(100, {shapiro.test(rands[[1]])$p.value
  })

y <- replicate(100, {set.seed(1); shapiro.test(rnorm(10) + c(1,0,2,0,1))$p.value
  })

all.equal(x,y)
[1] TRUE
```

So, you see that to get both identical, you need to force the random numbers in `y` to be identical. In `x`, you have precomputed them, which means you are running the same test on the same data 100 times, whereas in `y`, you are actually drawing new random numbers each time. So, to be clear, the right way to do this is your version `y` (not mine, where I set the seed inside the expression).

Comment: So obvious! Thanks! I think, there is no way to get what I wanted (or I need to create huge datasets, which I don't want).

Comment: I am not sure what you want, but it looks like your version `y` is correct.

Comment: Okay. I suspect you want to speed up the drawing of random numbers? That is tricky...

Comment: No, originaly, I wanted to plot what I tested, but it doesn't make sense: Which of the 100 samples do I want to choose? Your answer just hits the nail on the head.